# DataFrame : Convert array inside a column to RDD[Array[String]]

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe :

```
+---+----------+
|key|     value|
+---+----------+
|foo|       bar|
|bar|  one, two|
+---+----------+
```

Then I'd like to use the value column as entry to FPGrowth which must look like `RDD[Array[String]]`

```
val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = df.select("value").rdd.map(x => x.getList(0).toArray.map(_.toString))

import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.{FPGrowth, FPGrowthModel}
val fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(0.01)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)
```

I get exception :

```
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 141.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 141.0 (TID 2232, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
```

Any suggestion welcome !

Comment: the problem:  `df.select("value").rdd.map(x => x.getList(0)...`, because `x` is a string, it should be `x.getString(0)`

Comment: 1) `.getString(0)` change sequence to sequrnce of Char  `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Items in a transaction must be unique but got WrappedArray(o, n, e, ,, t, w, o).`    
2) The problem is the exception , that I cannot understand why

Comment: have you tried ..`val transactions =df.select("value").rdd.map(_.toString.split(","))`
`transactions: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[23] at map at <console>:35` . May be this should work as its returning an `RDD[Array[String]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of 
`val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = df.select("value").rdd.map(x => x.getList(0).toArray.map(_.toString))`

try using 
`val transactions= df.select("value").rdd.map(_.toString.stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]").split(","))`

It gives a desired ouptut as expected i.e. `RDD[Array[String]]`

```
val transactions= df.select("value").rdd.map(_.toString.stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]").split(","))
transactions: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[10] at map at <console>:33
scala> transactions.take(2)
res21: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(bar), Array(one, two))
```

To remove the  "[" and "]" ,one can use `stripPrefix` and `stripSuffix` function before `split` function.

Comment: I also tough that I'm missing `split` , after your suggestion splitting I get brackets  `[` with sting itself `[one` or `two]`

Comment: @Toren To get data without "[" and "]", we can use stripPrefix and stripSuffix function. Have updated the  code.